# Php multilanguage dynamic link

Tags: php, .htaccess, multilingual

There are two languages on my webpage. These are en and rs. ie english and russian. I want to be listed as en.php and rs.php under the languages directory, but only if they have the form url = ln = I, for example www.google.com/en or www.google.com/rs. For this I added the .htaccess file and the function.php file. but I do not know how to change the code I wrote below. How can I do that?

i have languages folder and en.php and tr.php

```
<?php
# Session başlat
  session_start();
$available_langs = array('en','tr');
$_SESSION['lng']='en';

 # Dil seçimi yapılmışsa
 if($_GET['lng']) {
# Dil seçimini session'a ata.
$_SESSION['lng'] = $_GET['lng'];
# Anasayfa'ya yönlendir.
   }
 if ($_SESSION['lng'] == "en") {
$lng = "en";
 }
elseif ($_SESSION['lng'] == "tr") {
$lng = "tr";
}

include 'languages/'.$lng.'.php';
  include("fonksiyon.php");
?>


    <li>
                                <?php
                                if(isset($_GET["lng"])){
                                    if($_GET["lng"] == "tr"){
                                        //echo '<a  href="?lng=en" style="text-decoration:none;"  title="English">EN</a>';
                                        echo ' <li style="float:left"> <a href="?lng=en" 
                                    style="border-left: solid gray 1px; line-height: 50%; margin-top: 15px; padding-right:2px; ">EN</a></li>';

                                    } else if($_GET["lng"] == "en"){
                                        // echo '<a href="?lng=tr" style="text-decoration:none;" title="Türkçe">TR</a>';
                                        echo ' <li style="float:left"> <a href="?lng=tr" 
                                     style="border-left: solid gray 1px; line-height: 50%; margin-top: 15px; padding-right:2px; ">TR</a></li>';
                                    } else {
                                        echo 'no lang';
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    //  echo '<a href="?lng=tr" style="text-decoration:none;" title="Türkçe">TR</a>';
                                    echo ' <li style="float:left"> <a href="?lng=tr"  style="border-left: solid gray 1px; 
                                    line-height: 50%; margin-top: 15px; padding-right:2px; ">TR</a></li>';
                                }
                                ?>
                            </li>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*).html$ roportajdetay.php?id=$1&$baslik=$2 [L,NC]
```

fonksiyon.php

```
<?php  function cevir($s) {


$tr = array('ş','Ş','ı','İ','ğ','Ğ','ü','Ü','ö','Ö','Ç','ç');


$eng = array('s','s','i','i','g','g','u','u','o','o','c','c');


$s = str_replace($tr,$eng,$s);


$s = strtolower($s);


$s = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $s);


$s = preg_replace('/[^%a-z0-9 _-]/', '', $s);


$s = preg_replace('/s+/', '-', $s);


$s = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $s);


$s = trim($s, '-');


return $s;


 } ?> ?>
```

Comment: First, that's a very broken link tag. Secondly, what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @Adam update my code. I want code extensions to be dynamic

Comment: you do have that closing brace `}` for the conditional, right?

Comment: @Adam `<a href="?lng=en"</a>` is valid, given that they're using an index file to reference it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner today I learned, thanks. I'm still quite unsure what they are wanting to do, but not sure if this warrants a "question unclear" flag or not.

Comment: You're welcome @Adam

Comment: the `.htaccess` should probably be included in the post. As it stands, your question's unclear for a few reasons. One of which I already asked about.

Comment: You can @Niner me or others; I don't want to be declared the winner in a staring game. Although I always win with playing that with cats ;-)

Comment: @FunkFortNiner i update my question

Comment: @Adam my question is update